# Display data from db onto browser from python using ajax and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, json

I have created a python file that fetches the data from MySQL db and encodes it into JSON format using 'json.dumps'.

I need to display this data on my browser using ajax and probably jQuery.
However, I am unable to understand how I can get the data in my JavaScript code and then accordingly use the data as per my wish on the google map that I have created.

Please help me with the code.

I am attaching the python and html code.

**Python code**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import MySQLdb

import json

db = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "***", db = "client_database")

cursor = db.cursor ()

cursor.execute ("select FULL_NAME, EMAIL_ID, MOBILE, GENDER, AREA_OF_EXPERTISE, YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE  from client_info")

data = cursor.fetchall()

display = json.dumps(data, indent=4)

cursor.close ()

db.close ()
```

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DevMap</title>

    <style>
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        } 

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #description {
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 300;
        }

        #infowindow-content.title {
            display: none;
        }


        #map #infowindow-content {
            display: none;
        }

        .pac-card {
            margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
            border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: Calibri;
        }

        #pac-container {
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            margin-right: 12px;
        }

        .pac-controls {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 5px 11px;
        }

        .pac-controls label {
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 400;
        }

        #pac-input {
            background-color: white;
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: 18px;
            margin-left: 12px;
            padding: 15px 15px;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            width: 500px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 6px;
        }

        #pac-input:focus {
            border-color: #00015E;
        }

        #title {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #4d90fe;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding: 6px 12px;
        }

        #target {
            width: 345px;
        }

        #form {
            overflow: scroll;
            display: none;
        }

        #heading {
            text-align: center;
            color: #003366;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: Calibri;
            padding: 8px 12px;
        }

        label.field {
            text-align: left;
            font-weight: bolder;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: Calibri;
        }

        input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=number], select {
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bolder;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        input[type=submit] {
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bolder;
            background-color: white;
            color: #00A200;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: 2px solid #00A200;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        input[type=submit]:hover {
            background-color: #00A200;
            color: white;
        }

        input[type=reset] {
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bolder;
            background-color: white;
            color: #cc0000;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: 2px solid #cc0000;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        input[type=reset]:hover {
            background-color: #cc0000;
            color: white;
        }

        input[type=text]:focus {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            border-color: #4d90fe;
        }

        input[type=email]:focus {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            border-color: #4d90fe;
        }

        input[type=number]:focus {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            border-color: #4d90fe;
        }

        select:focus {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            border-color: #4d90fe;
        }

        #overlay {
            position: fixed;
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
            z-index: 1;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .box { 
            /* Linear gradient - By default left to right - (direction, color1, color2) */    
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, aqua, royalblue); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(right, aqua, royalblue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, aqua, royalblue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
            background: linear-gradient(to right, aqua , royalblue); /* Standard syntax */  
            background-color: #F1C40F;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Calibri;
            color: midnightblue;
            font-size: 60px;
            font-weight:bold;
            margin:200px auto;
            height:70px;
            width: 100%;        
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;   
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        .button {
            overflow: hidden;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #FF0000;
            border: 0.5px solid;
            border-color: #000000;
            border-radius: 6px;
            width: 160px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 10px 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: bold;
            position: relative;
        }

        .button:hover {
            background-color: #AB0000;
        }

        .wrapper {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=********************&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
            async defer>
    </script>   

</head>

<body onload="on()">
    <!-- Overlay with logo. -->
    <div id="overlay">
        <div class="box">DevMap</div>
        <!-- Register/Find Developer button. -->
        <div class="wrapper">
        <button class="button" onclick="off()">Register Yourself!</button>
        <button class="button" onclick="off()">Find Developers!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Creating form to display inside infowindow. -->
    <div id="map"></div>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter your location here..." />
    <div id="form">
        <form action="/cgi-bin/processing.py" method="post">
        <p id="heading">PERSONAL INFORMATION</p>
        <label class="field" for="fullname"><b>Full Name:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Eg. Suraj Makhija" size="30" required />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label class="field" for="emailid"><b>E-mail:</b></label>
        <input type="email" name="emailid" placeholder="Eg. contact@domain.com" size="30" required />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label class="field" for="mobile"><b>Mobile:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Eg. 9999999999" maxlength="10" minlength="10" size="30" required />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label class="field" for="gender"><b>Gender:</b></label>
        <select name="gender" required>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label class="field" for="areaofexpertise"><b>Area of Expertise:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="areaofexpertise" placeholder="Eg. Android/iOS Developer" size="30" required />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label class="field" for="yearsofexperience"><b>Years of Experience:</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="yearsofexperience" placeholder="Eg. 10" min="0" max="100" required />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="hidden" name="location_lat" id="lat">
        <input type="hidden" name="location_lng" id="lng">
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
        <input type="reset" value="Clear All" /> 
        </p>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        var map;
        var iconBase;
        var input;
        var searchBox;   
        var markers=[];         
        var markerArray =[];
        var infowindow;
        //Declaring different markers for male/female.
        var customIcon = {
            male: {
                iconBase : 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
            },
            female: {
                iconBase : 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png'
            }
        };

        //Overlay function.
        function on() {
            document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
        }
        function off() {
            document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
        }

        //Declaring map function.
        function initAutocomplete() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: 20.5937, lng: 78.9629},
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
                gestureHandling: 'cooperative'
            });

        //Declaring infowindow.
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: document.getElementById('form')
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
            searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        //Creates a marker when the user clicks on a location on the map.
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            addMarker(event.latLng, map);
        });

        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
            if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        });

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
                console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                return;
            }
        var icon = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };
        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
        }));
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
    }

        //Marker function declaration.
        function addMarker(location, map) {
        // Add the marker at the clicked location.
            var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/';
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: location,
            map: map,
            icon: iconBase + 'ylw-blank.png'
        });
        //Infowindow pops up on clicking the marker.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            document.getElementById('form').style.display='inline-block';
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
        var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
        document.getElementById('lat').value=lat;
        document.getElementById('lng').value=lng;
    }
        //Trying AJAX to run
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.FULL_NAME;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/cgi-bin/display.py", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: are you able to see the response json when you directly hit below url ?     base-path/cgi-bin/display.py   (replace base path with initial url). please share the output also.

Comment: You will need to setup a Python HTTP server. There are built-in modules and a bunch of third party modules for this task. Which one you should pick depends on your needs. You will probably need to do more research and then come back with a specific programming question, because your question is currently too broad.

Comment: It shows not found on this server when I directly hit the url. I am using Pycharm for python so when I use display = json.dumps(data, indent=4) and print display, it shows the data from db in the form of array of arrays. @ShivangAgarwal

Comment: @SurajMakhija yes exactly here is the issue . actually for access this data over http you need to setup http server. you can't access them directly for the purpose of deep understanding i asked you to check it first. there is many modules which is already developed you can choice any one of them. https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html